# Performance loss if function is not defined in class declaration

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, hpc

I have a high performance code which includes the class that is found at the bottom of this post. My problem is that as soon as I do not define the advecu function in the class declaration, but instead separate the declaration and the implementation (as I prefer), I lose a considerable amount of performance in both the Intel C++ and the Clang compilers. I do not, however, understand why. When I remove the templates, the performance is the same for both ways on all compilers.

```
template<bool dim3>
struct Advec4Kernel
{
  static void advecu(double * restrict ut, double * restrict u, double * restrict v, double * restrict w, double * restrict dzi4, const Grid &grid)
  {
    int    ijk,kstart,kend;
    int    ii1,ii2,ii3,jj1,jj2,jj3,kk1,kk2,kk3;
    double dxi,dyi;

    ii1 = 1;
    ii2 = 2;
    ii3 = 3;
    jj1 = 1*grid.icells;
    jj2 = 2*grid.icells;
    jj3 = 3*grid.icells;
    kk1 = 1*grid.ijcells;
    kk2 = 2*grid.ijcells;
    kk3 = 3*grid.ijcells;

    kstart = grid.kstart;
    kend   = grid.kend;

    dxi = 1./grid.dx;
    dyi = 1./grid.dy;

    for(int k=grid.kstart; k<grid.kend; k++)
      for(int j=grid.jstart; j<grid.jend; j++)
        for(int i=grid.istart; i<grid.iend; i++)
        {
          ijk = i + j*jj1 + k*kk1;
          ut[ijk] -= ( cg0*((ci0*u[ijk-ii3] + ci1*u[ijk-ii2] + ci2*u[ijk-ii1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]) * (ci0*u[ijk-ii3] + ci1*u[ijk-ii2] + ci2*u[ijk-ii1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]))
                     + cg1*((ci0*u[ijk-ii2] + ci1*u[ijk-ii1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+ii1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-ii2] + ci1*u[ijk-ii1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+ii1]))
                     + cg2*((ci0*u[ijk-ii1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+ii1] + ci3*u[ijk+ii2]) * (ci0*u[ijk-ii1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+ii1] + ci3*u[ijk+ii2]))
                     + cg3*((ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+ii1] + ci2*u[ijk+ii2] + ci3*u[ijk+ii3]) * (ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+ii1] + ci2*u[ijk+ii2] + ci3*u[ijk+ii3])) ) * cgi*dxi;

          if(dim3)
          {
            ut[ijk] -= ( cg0*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2-jj1] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1-jj1] + ci2*v[ijk-jj1] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1-jj1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-jj3] + ci1*u[ijk-jj2] + ci2*u[ijk-jj1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]))
                       + cg1*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2    ] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1    ] + ci2*v[ijk    ] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1    ]) * (ci0*u[ijk-jj2] + ci1*u[ijk-jj1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+jj1]))
                       + cg2*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2+jj1] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1+jj1] + ci2*v[ijk+jj1] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1+jj1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-jj1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+jj1] + ci3*u[ijk+jj2]))
                       + cg3*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2+jj2] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1+jj2] + ci2*v[ijk+jj2] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1+jj2]) * (ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+jj1] + ci2*u[ijk+jj2] + ci3*u[ijk+jj3])) ) * cgi*dyi;
          }

          ut[ijk] -= ( cg0*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2-kk1] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1-kk1] + ci2*w[ijk-kk1] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1-kk1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-kk3] + ci1*u[ijk-kk2] + ci2*u[ijk-kk1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]))
                     + cg1*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2    ] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1    ] + ci2*w[ijk    ] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1    ]) * (ci0*u[ijk-kk2] + ci1*u[ijk-kk1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+kk1]))
                     + cg2*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2+kk1] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1+kk1] + ci2*w[ijk+kk1] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1+kk1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-kk1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+kk1] + ci3*u[ijk+kk2]))
                     + cg3*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2+kk2] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1+kk2] + ci2*w[ijk+kk2] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1+kk2]) * (ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+kk1] + ci2*u[ijk+kk2] + ci3*u[ijk+kk3])) )
                     * dzi4[k];
        }
  }
};
```

The separated version looks as:

```
// header
template<bool dim3>
struct Advec4Kernel
{
  static void advecu(double *, double *, double *, double *, double *, const Grid &);
}

// source
template<bool dim3>
void Advec4Kernel<dim3>::advecu(double * restrict ut, double * restrict u, double * restrict v, double * restrict w, double * restrict dzi4, const Grid &grid)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a failure to inline. Have you looked at the generated code?

Comment: When you separate it, did you mark it as `inline`? Is the definition available to the code that uses the function, *before* its use?

Comment: Show how you separate them, please. Is `dim3` still a template parameter in that case?

Comment: I guess you meant defined and not declared... If a member-function is not declared in the class definition, it cannot be declared anywhere else either.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I tried using the inline keyword, but it does not solve the problem. The definition must be available before I use it, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Chiel: You are the one that has access to the code, don't ask me :) Template processing is non-trivial, and not all compilers follow the same rules, you could run `g++ -E` on the source file and check manually what the compiler is looking at, there you should be able to verify whether the function is defined *before* all uses

Comment: This is such a big function I'd be very surprising inlining is the reason. Could you post the exact code of your seperated-but-in-header case, that has the performance degrade?

Comment: If you add inline to the separated version does it change the peformance?

Comment: What is the exact measured performance difference? Are you measuring under the same conditions?

Comment: @RichardHodges In clang it is about 5%, but in GCC I measure more than 10%

Comment: When moving out the code to a separate compilation unit, are you sure that you also specified the same optimization options as with the code using your inline version? (e.g. "-O3" or -ffast-math)

Comment: @oxygene Yes, I use an automated build system. I have even tried to split them in the same file, with the same performance loss as a result.

Comment: @Chiel Maybe put `restrict` in the declaration too, like it is in the definition?

Comment: @Chiel Also, did you look at the code generated by the compiler?

Comment: @anatolyg Assembly largely intimidates me for this example. I do not have enough experience to make anything out of that.

Comment: If you add inline to the separated version does it change the peformance?

Comment: @NeilKirk that does not help.

Comment: @anatolyg Adding restrict in the declaration solves the problem. I don't understand why, but it does! If you write an answer, including an explanation I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the compiler performs some optimizations using the [`restrict`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) keyword. To benefit from these optimizations, the function's *declaration* must contain the `restrict` keyword. This was [determined empirically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905430/performance-loss-if-function-is-not-defined-in-class-declaration?noredirect=1#comment44214308_27905430); I don't know whether it's a compiler deficiency or a law.

Code:

```
// header
template<bool dim3>
struct Advec4Kernel
{
  static void advecu(double *restrict, double *restrict, double *restrict, double *restrict, double *restrict, const Grid &);
}
```

Comment: It cannot really be "the law," since `restrict` in C++ is a compiler extension, not part of the standard.

Comment: @Angew I agree with this, nonetheless, this solves my problem on the Clang and Intel C++ compilers. I would still like to know the explanation

Comment: @Chiel Then you'll have to consult the documentation of these compilers, specifically how they handle their `restrict` extension.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that are defined inside the class declarations are inlined in most cases and thats why there is a performance degrade

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason? It's such a huge function.

Comment: @NeilKirk That is what I thought as well. This problem is puzzling me for a long time now, and I prefer to stay away from putting the implementation in the class declaration. I could remove the templates, but that would introduce a large amount of code duplication.

Comment: @Chiel When templates are involved, I just put it in the class definition, as it's easier. In this case, couldn't the bool flag just be a class member?

Comment: @Neil No, I need to use templates, because if statements in the inner loop kill the performance entirely.

Comment: @Chiel If you want to avoid having to put function template bodies in headers and the domain of the template arguments is limited (just 2 values with `bool`, for example), you can leave the definitions in a source file and explicitly instantiate them.